# How to find if the field is not editable using selenium in java

Tags: java, selenium, action

I want to validate and make sure that the fields under 7 columns are not editable

I have used list to store all the elements with a particular tag and then iterate over the list to check if it is editable/clickable/having any input despite it is blank or not

```
By mySelector = By.xpath("//div[@col-id='PROCESSOR1']");
    List<WebElement> myElements = driver.findElements(mySelector);
    for (WebElement e : myElements) {
        String text = e.getAttribute("title");
        System.out.println("Found etxt: " + text);

        if (text.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("input box is empty");
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@col-id='PROCESSOR1']")).click() {
                System.out.println("Text case pass:");
                break;
            }

        }
    }
```

**DIV LOOKS LIKE:**

```
div tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" comp-id="1534" col-id="PROCESSOR" class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-with-height ag-cell-value ag-cell-no-focus" style="width: 97px; left: 1864px; "
```

[image]

Comment: check if the class have  `ag-cell-not-inline-editing`. That should make sure the cell is not editable.

Comment: all the class has that value. Only difference between editable and non editable is of input tag after div tag.. can you please reply me by providing code snippet @supputuri

Comment: Please share the html of the input and parent div.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the attribute `read-only` for the element in DOM. If its set to true, file is not editable.

Comment: I have updated the descirption, can you please help according to that @prena pal

Comment: Its not very clear from the posted snapshot. Please refer this link which might be of help for you https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_contenteditable.asp